# Cannot add multiple .ned directory when running omnet++ from its own shell

Tags: mingw, omnet++

I want to run my simulation without opening the IDE. I checked the manual and follow the steps but I got stucked. 
I am using omnetpp v5.6.2. I run mingwenv.cmd in the directory where my *.ini is and type this:

```
AFDX.exe -f C:/Workspaces/Github/AFDX/Simulations/AutoNetwork.ini -n C:/Workspaces/Github/AFDX/simulations
```

I got this in return:

```
OMNeT++ Discrete Event Simulation  (C) 1992-2019 Andras Varga, OpenSim Ltd.
Version: 5.6.2, build: 200518-aa79d0918f, edition: Academic Public License -- NOT FOR COMMERCIAL USE
See the license for distribution terms and warranty disclaimer

Setting up Qtenv...

Loading NED files from C:/Workspaces/Github/AFDX/simulations:  1

Loading images from 'bitmaps': *: 0
Loading images from 'images': *: 0
Loading images from 'C:/omnetpp-5.6.2/images': *: 0  abstract/*: 90  background/*: 4  block/*: 320  device/*: 195  logo/*: 1  maps/*: 9  misc/*: 70  msg/*: 55  old/*: 111  status/*: 28
```

and this:

[image: error]

So I added my src directory too

```
AFDX.exe -f C:/Workspaces/Github/AFDX/Simulations/AutoNetwork.ini -n "C:/Workspaces/Github/AFDX/simulations;C:/Workspaces/Github/AFDX/src"
```

This time I make it count all the ned files but still didn't work:

```
OMNeT++ Discrete Event Simulation  (C) 1992-2019 Andras Varga, OpenSim Ltd.
Version: 5.6.2, build: 200518-aa79d0918f, edition: Academic Public License -- NOT FOR COMMERCIAL USE
See the license for distribution terms and warranty disclaimer

Setting up Qtenv...

Loading NED files from C:/Workspaces/Github/AFDX/simulations:  1
Loading NED files from C:/Workspaces/Github/AFDX/src:  38

Loading images from 'bitmaps': *: 0
Loading images from 'images': *: 0
Loading images from 'C:/omnetpp-5.6.2/images': *: 0  abstract/*: 90  background/*: 4  block/*: 320  device/*: 195  logo/*: 1  maps/*: 9  misc/*: 70  msg/*: 55  old/*: 111  status/*: 28
```

[image]

As opposed to the error, there is an AFDX::ConnDef class actually and **when I run the simulation by using the IDE, it works just fine.**

I am adding my project directory structure too, maybe it'll help.

|>AFDX
__|>src
____|>queueinglib
______| *.ned
______| *.cc
______| *.h
____| *.ned
____| *.cc
____| *.h
____| **ConnDef stuff is here**
__|>simulations
____|>Results
____|AFDX.exe
____|AutoNetwork.ini
____|AutoNetwork.ned
____|Makefile
__|Makefile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question contains 2 problems. The first was properly solved by you. The second (`afdx::ConnDef` not found). Has absolutely nothing to do with the title of this question or with NED files in general. The `ConnDef` class is either missing from the c++ code, or you forgot to add the `Define_Module` macro, or you put that class into the global namespace instead of including it the `afdx` namespace.

You are suggesting that you get different results running from IDE or the commandline. This can be only, of you actually run different executables.

Checking your directory tree shows that you have a `Makefile` and the 'AFDX.exe' file in the `simulations` folder, so that folder is designated as *source folder*, however it does NOT have any source files in it. On the other hand, `src` folder is also a *source folder* and while you have not indicated, I believe it also has a `Makefile` and again an EXE file, and **that** is the executable that contains your model code and the `afdx::ConnDef` class (and the IDE also starts that executable). On the other hand, you are launching the EXE file from the `simulations` folder which is an empty exe without any code...

Do NOT use two source folders in a project at the same time unless you really now what you are doing. Just remove the source designation from the `simulations` folder and delete the exe and Makefile there.

Use the EXE in the `src` folder to start the sim from command-line. i.e. you would do something like

```
cd simulations
../src/AFDX.exe -n ".;../src" AutoNetwork.ini
```

Comment: I understand the logic but I can run this simulation from the IDE successfully without changing anything about Conndef. What is the difference when not using the IDE?

Comment: Indeed, running from IDE or the command line should give you exactly the same results. That tells me that you are not running the same executable file, and that's why teh behavior is different. See my edit of the answer.

Comment: Oh, and BTW, if you would use OMNeT++ 5.7, that version dumps the command line it is using on the IDE console, so you can copy/paste the actual command to console

Comment: Ok, I remove the source designation and I move AutoNetwork.ned to src. Addition to that I had to add package to the ned file and update ini file according to that. But it works now. Thanks!

Comment: In fact, you could have kept the AutoNetwork.ned in the simulations folder. As long as both src and simulations are added as a ned folder, that woud be fine. But, as long as you don1t want to distribute your work to otehr people, this setup is also fine.

Comment: When I leave AutoNetwork.ned in the simulations folder while simulation folder's source designation is removed, I got this error:  "<!> Error: Network 'AutoNetwork' not found, check .ini and .ned files"

Comment: NED folder designation for the simulations folder should remain, only the C++ source folder designation should be removed.

Comment: Those are seperate things? I change this setting in "NED Source Folders" section in project properties. So this setting changes NED or source designation?

Comment: Yes those are separate things. You should have both the simulations and the src folder as NED source folder, but only 'src' as a C++ source folder. C++ source folders are specified  on the projetc properties OMNeT++ / Makemake dialog page, while NED source folders on OMNeT++ / NED SOurce folders.

Comment: Oh I understood now. But my when I was having this original problem that I mentioned in the question, simulations folder's soruce designation was disabled (from Makemake dialog page) and ned source folder designation is enabled. It is only resolved when I remove ned source folder designation of "simulations" folder and move AutoNetwork.ned to folder "src" .